# Why the GUI is taking so much time to show up?

Tags: java, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I'm working on a simple file explorer in javaFX with SceneBuilder. Everything seems to work fine except when I launch the app, it is taking up to 10 minutes to actually displaying the GUI. I can assume it is because it is reading all the files and folders inside all the drives !

The app is consisted of a `TreeView` that list all the drives and TableView to show the data inside the drives. I'm guessing the long delay is caused by a wrong implementation in the below code.

Here is how I'm populating the treeView:

```
@Override
public TreeItem<String>[] TreeCreate(File dir){
    TreeItem<String>[] item;
    File[] fl = dir.listFiles();
    int n= fl.length - FilesHiddensCount(dir);
    item = new TreeItem[n];
    int pos = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<fl.length; i++){

        if(!fl[i].isFile()&& !fl[i].isHidden() && fl[i].isDirectory() && n == 0) {
            item[pos] = new TreeItem<>(fl[i].getName(),
                     new ImageView(new Image(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("img/folderOpen.png")))); pos++;}
        else if(!fl[i].isFile()&& !fl[i].isHidden() && fl[i].isDirectory() && n>0){
            item[pos] = new TreeItem<>(fl[i].getName(),
                    new ImageView(new Image(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("img/folderOpen.png"))));
            try{
                item[pos].getChildren().addAll(TreeCreate(fl[i]));
                pos++;
            }catch(Exception x){
                System.out.println("Exception x in treecreate at "+fl[i].getAbsolutePath()+" "+x.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    return item;
}
```

Creating the threeView:

```
 @Override
public void CreateTreeView(TreeView<String> treeview){
    File[] sysroots = File.listRoots();
    TreeItem<String> ThisPc = new TreeItem<>("This PC", new ImageView(new Image(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("img/pc.png"))));
    TreeItem<String>[] drives = new TreeItem[sysroots.length];
    for(int i=0; i<sysroots.length;i++){
        drives[i] = new TreeItem<>(sysroots[i].getAbsolutePath(), new ImageView(new Image(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("img/thumb_Hard_Drive.png"))));
        try{
            drives[i].getChildren().addAll(TreeCreate(sysroots[i]));
        }catch(NullPointerException x){
            System.out.println("Exeption x detected: "+x.fillInStackTrace()+drives[i].toString());
        }
        finally {
            ThisPc.getChildren().add(drives[i]);
        }
    }
    treeview.setRoot(ThisPc);
}
```

After at leat 7 minutes, the UI shows up (finally):
[image]

However, the log is showing some weird exceptions before the GUI shows up:

```
Exception x in treecreate at C:\Documents and Settings null
Exception x in treecreate at C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\388.13\Win10_64\International\Display.Driver null
Exception x in treecreate at C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\388.13\Win10_64\International\Display.NView null
Exception x in treecreate at C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\388.13\Win10_64\International\Display.Optimus null
Exception x in treecreate at C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\388.13\Win10_64\International\Display.Update null
Exception x in treecreate at C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\388.13\Win10_64\International\GFExperience null
Exception x in treecreate at C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\388.13\Win10_64\International\GFExperience.NvStreamSrv null
Exception x in treecreate at C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\388.13\Win10_64\International\HDAudio null
Exception x in treecreate at C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\388.13\Win10_64\International\MSVCRT null
Exception x in treecreate at C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\388.13\Win10_64\International\nodejs null
Exception x in treecreate at C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\388.13\Win10_64\International\NV3DVision null
Exception x in treecreate at C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\388.13\Win10_64\International\NV3DVisionUSB.Driver null
Exception x in treecreate at C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\388.13\Win10_64\International\NvBackend null
Exception x in treecreate at C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\388.13\Win10_64\International\NvCamera null
Exception x in treecreate at C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\388.13\Win10_64\International\NvContainer null
Exception x in treecreate at C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\388.13\Win10_64\International\NVI2 null
Exception x in treecreate at C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\388.13\Win10_64\International\NvTelemetry null
Exception x in treecreate at C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\388.13\Win10_64\International\NvVAD null
Exception x in treecreate at C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\388.13\Win10_64\International\NvvHCI null
Exception x in treecreate at C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\388.13\Win10_64\International\NVWMI null
Exception x in treecreate at C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\388.13\Win10_64\International\PhysX null
Exception x in treecreate at C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\388.13\Win10_64\International\ShadowPlay null
Exception x in treecreate at C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\388.13\Win10_64\International\ShieldWirelessController null
Exception x in treecreate at C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\388.13\Win10_64\International\Update.Core null
Exception x in treecreate at C:\PerfLogs null
```

Any way to avoid or reduce the long delay?

Comment: _I can assume it is because it is reading all the files and folders inside all the drives !_ yes, that's probably it. Instead of building a complete list of all files when opening the dialog, you could build the list on the fly: First show a node "This PC". Then, whenever the user clicks an item in the tree widget, find the sub folders and add them to the tree (without recursion).

Comment: `item[pos].getChildren().addAll(TreeCreate(fl[i]));` is doing a recursive scan of all the drives and all their child directories ... this is not a fast process.  You should be using a lazy approach, where you just scan the top level directories. When the user opens a directory, you then scan it's contents

Comment: Thanks for your tips, I'm going to try another approach

Comment: Note that you're responsible for the "weird excepions". The info you print is just a small part of the info available in a `Exception`. Printing the full stacktrace would provide you with some insight about the issue.

Comment: Would, any of you, mind sharing snipets? This will help me alot figure out what to do . Thank you

Comment: Yes fabian, thanks